# Refactor switch statement that depends on parent object being defined

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I'm just wondering if there is a better way to write this in Javascript (specifically getting rid of the if statement).

**that.conflicts_selected** is an object in the form of `{text: "All Locations", value: "all"}`

However, sometimes that.conflicts_selected can be null, which is the reason for the if statement.

```
        if (that.conflicts_selected) {
          switch (that.conflicts_selected.value) {
            case "all":
              return true;
            case "with":
              return (someValue > 0)
            case "without":
              return (someValue === 0)
          }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the curiously-powerful `&&` operator:

```
switch (that.conflicts_selected && that.conflicts_selected.value) {
  case "all":
    return true;
  case "with":
    return (someValue > 0)
  case "without":
    return (someValue === 0)
}
```

`that.conflicts_selected && that.conflicts_selected.value` is evaluated like this:

- The left-hand side (`that.conflicts_selected`) is evaluated

  - If the resulting value is *falsy* (`null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, or of course, `false`) the overall `&&` expression takes that value as its result.
  - If the left-hand side's resulting value is *truthy* (any value that isn't falsy), the right-hand side (`that.conflicts_selected.value`) is evaluated and the `&&` expression takes that as its result.

That means that it short-circuits in the falsy case, so if `that.conflicts_selected` is `null`, you won't get an error trying to access a property (`value`) on `null` (`that.conflicts_selected`).

Once the `switch` value (`that.conflicts_selected && that.conflicts_selected.value`) is evaluated, it's then checked against the `case` labels. Unlike other languages with similar syntax, the `case` labels don't have to be constants, they can be expressions (although they are constants in this example, they're string literals). The first `case` label in source-code order is evaluated, and its result compared with the `switch` value using strict (`===`) comparison, and if it's a match the `case`'s statements are executed; if not, the next `case` label is evaluated and compared, etc. If none of them match and there's a `default`, its statements are executed; if there's no `default`, no statements in the `switch`' `case`s are executed.

This looks slightly odd when you first start working with JavaScript, but it's a well-established idiom you'll soon get used to.

Comment: You're right that does look a little odd. I didn't think you could do that. How does the order of operations work for the switch cases though? Is it left to right in this example?

Comment: @phil - Not sure what you mean about left-to-right. JavaScript's `switch`/`case` is a bit different from other languages with a similar construct: Case labels can be arbitrary expressions (in your case they're just string literals), and they're checked against the `switch` value in source code order with a strict equality (`===`) comparison. If none match and there's a `default`, that's the code that runs; if none match and there's no `default` (above), nothing happens.

Comment: @phil - Added detail in the answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it that is also easily extendable is using an object.

```
const valueEvaluators {
    all: val => true,
    with: val => val > 0,
    without: val => val === 0
}

return that.conflicts_selected && valueEvaluators[that.conflicts_selected.value](someValue)
```

Comment: *"I would do just one change on null handling"* Ah, you saw that? Drat, I thought I fixed it before anyone saw. :-) (Note: Your `switch` is missing `"all"`, and there's no need for `default: break;`)

Comment: Oh gosh I missed the `all` in they copy, and yeah there is no need.

Comment: The value evaluator is a good approach for some situations, though note that the above always involves a return, whereas the OP's code doesn't (it carries on past the `if` when there's no match).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Correct, I would just want to "do nothing" for the null case

Comment: @phil well, being javascript if you return nothing the function still returns `undefined` so returning `that.conflicts_selected` if it's `null` would be basically the same.

Comment: @J.Pichardo You're right, I misunderstood. Just tested it for my specific case and it does fix my problem. The only issue I am having is that the return statement seems a little convoluted and difficult to follow (probably cause I'm a newbie).

Comment: No, you are right, that approach is extensible but lacks readability.

Comment: This is a new type of approach that I would have never thought of. Thank you for teaching me something new today! I will definitely use it in more logically complex code.